# Setting digits from a number to a specific position in an array

Tags: c#, arrays

I am trying to implement numbers `[0..999]` to a certain position in an array. Example:

```
number: 9 - array: 009 /// number 78 - array 078 /// number 245 - array 245.
```

This is my source code and it works, but are there any simpler methods to do the task, which might be useful in case the number is bigger?

```
uint check;
uint[] number= new uint[3];

while (true)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Input number");
  string input = Console.ReadLine();
  if (uint.TryParse(input, out check))
  {
    if (check < 10)
    {
      number[2] = Convert.ToUInt32(Convert.ToString(input[0]));
      break;
    }
    else if (check < 100)
    {
      number[1] = Convert.ToUInt32(Convert.ToString(input[0]));
      number[2] = Convert.ToUInt32(Convert.ToString(input[1]));
      break;
    }
    else if (check < 1000)
    {
      number[0] = Convert.ToUInt32(Convert.ToString(input[0]));
      number[1] = Convert.ToUInt32(Convert.ToString(input[1]));
      number[2] = Convert.ToUInt32(Convert.ToString(input[2]));
      break;
    }
    else
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Out of range. Try again");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: As a side-note: you do not have to set every value in your number[] array to 0 - C# has a default constructor for every value type, and will always initialize ints to 0.

Comment: Just because I love Linq: var number = input.PadLeft(3,'0').Select(c => char.IsNumber(c) ? (uint)(c - '0') : 0u).ToArray();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the modulo operator, along these lines:

```
if (uint.TryParse(input, out check))
{
   if (check < 1000)
   {
     number[2] = check % 10; //gets last digit
     check /= 10; //"shaves off" last digit

     number[1] = check % 10;
     check /= 10; 

     number[0] = check % 10; 
   }
   else
   {
     Console.WriteLine("Out of range. Try again");
   }
}
```

Note that in this way you might be able to digitize an arbitrary large number, not just sub-1000 numbers, with code like:

```
List<int> digits = new List<int>();
if (uint.TryParse(input, out check))
{
   while (check != 0)
   {
      digits.Insert(0, check % 10);
      check /=10;
   }
}
int[] digitsArray = digits.ToArray();
```

Comment: You have 2 divisions in a loop: `check % 10` and `check /= 10`. You could divide only once using the `Math.DivRem` method. And also the total number of digits in the result can be calculated before iterating.

Comment: `DivRem` always looks counter-intuitive to me, and it's not less code (at least until C#6)

Comment: `Math.DivRem` only works on signed ints, OP used uints.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this method could be helpful. It converts a given `number` to the array of digits:

```
private static int[] NumberToArray(int number)
{
    int[] digits = new int[(int)(Math.Log10(number) + 0.999999)];

    int i = digits.Length - 1;
    while (number >= 10)
    {
        int rem;
        number = Math.DivRem(number, 10, out rem);
        digits[i--] = rem;
    }
    digits[0] = number;
    return digits;
}
```

*Here the `int` type used because of `Math.DivRem` accepts signed types only.*